# Getting the current module name

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there a way to get the name of the module you are working within? I have a large set of modules (about 35) with some common functionality. Long story short is that I would like to be able to get the module name without hard-coding it in a string. Hopefully this isn't necessary, but here's an idea of what I'm trying for:

```
function MYMODULE_mycustom_hook($args) {
    $sCurrModule = 'MYMODULE';

    // Operations using $sCurrModule...
}
```

Essentially, I can replace 'MYMODULE' with the module name and be done with it, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get that value programmatically. I'm using Drupal 7.

**This does not apply to Drupal 8.**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your module file is `sites/default/modules/MYMODULE/MYMODULE.module` then module name is MYMODULE.

You can get it programmatically inside MYMODULE.module file using following command:

```
$module_name = basename(__FILE__, '.module');
```

Comment: CAVEAT: this does not work if the code is outside the `.module` file which is almost always the case for any non-trivial functionality.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer accepted either: Regarding D8 .module file is often used.

Comment: if you look at the tags, you'll notice this is for Drupal 7. It's marked as the accepted answer because it solved my problem.

Comment: CAVEAT: the `$module_name` variable is not namespaced to a specific class or module, so you may get unexpected results if you are using this across multiple modules.

Comment: Fair observation; for my implementation I never needed it outside of a specific function, but others who might just drop that into the top of the file could be in trouble.

Answer (score 8):

Although OP was asking regarding D7, here's the solution for Drupal 8 (D8) as well:

```
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandlerInterface $module_handler */
$module_handler = \Drupal::service('module_handler');

/** @var \Drupal\Core\Extension\Extension $module_object */
$module_object = $module_handler->getModule(basename(__FILE__, '.module'));

$module_name = $module_object->getName();
```

Of course, you can chain these calls if necessary:

```
\Drupal::service('module_handler')->getModule(basename(__FILE__, '.module'))->getName()
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but the question was not regarding Drupal 8.

Comment: @Lawrence Johnson As you probably see, the very first sentence of my answer was acknowledging the fact you pointed out: _"Although OP was asking regarding D7 [...]"_. I hope you don't mind that I tried to share a piece of experience hopefully useful for some others.

Comment: I think it's great, and I upvoted the answer as well. I don't think it's great, however, to retag my question as Drupal 8.

Comment: As @dreftymac correctly points out his solution works only within rare circumstances when this code ran in a *.module file.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly said in comments

```
 basename(__FILE__, '.module');
```

only works inside an actual .module file.

Answering to question:

1. inside your MYMODULE.module

   ```
   function  print_current_module_name()  {
     return  basename(__FILE__, '.module');
   }
   ```
2. from everywhere in Drupal >8

   ```
   $module_name = print_current_module_name();
   echo "module name is : " . $module_name
   ```

Not sure this will work on  Drupal 7 as well

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky but still easy and reliable in most cases:

`public function getModuleName() { return explode('\\', __CLASS__)[1]; }`

Since a third party module class namespace should have **Drupal\my_module_name** as a prefix, this will return the expected value.